# How do I log out of Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

Sorry - I'm new here, but I couldn't find how to log out of askubuntu.com again.  Did I just miss it? Is logging out of askubuntu.com the same as logging out of the Ubuntu Software Centre, which seems not to be possible? ([How do I logout of Ubuntu Software Center? (Seriously, where's the logout button?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150184/how-do-i-logout-of-ubuntu-software-center-seriously-wheres-the-logout-button))

If you can log in, why can't you log out?

Answer (score 6):

1. Click on the "callout" icon at the top right.
2. Click "[log out](https://askubuntu.com/users/logout)"

[image: Logout]

Answer (score 3):

> I'm new here

Welcome!

> Is logging out of askubuntu.com the same as logging out of the Ubuntu Software Centre, which seems not to be possible?

And no, askubuntu.com and the Software Center are two completely different logins, managed by two different, completed unrelated companies:

- Software Center is an application created and managed by Canonical Ltd., the creators of Ubuntu.
- Ask Ubuntu, on the other hand, is owned and managed by Stack Exchange, Inc. which has no relation to Canonical (although we often see users have confusion on that point).

> If you can log in, why can't you log out?

As [the other current answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19912/1165986) clarifies, this is not [Hotel California](https://open.spotify.com/track/40riOy7x9W7GXjyGp4pjAv?si=91a50276c27c44c6) -- You can check out, and you *can* leave.

But we do hope you'll stick around!

Comment: Thanks all!   my bad for not seeing it - I've brought my alibi and I will stick around.